# Change color of popup (angular, TS)

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, styles

I build a custom popup which is visible when I click a button. When I click somewhere else on the document the popup should be closed / invisible.
That works pretty well.
Now I want to change the style property of this popup. The problem is that i cant change it.
The code below returns that the HTML object is null but if i click another buttom with same functionality the style changes.

Thats my code so far

tooltip.component.ts

```
export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {
  popup = false;

  // open popup
  openToolTip($event: {
    target: any; stopPropagation: () => void; 
  }) 
  {
    
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.popup = !this.popup;
    
   testvariable = document.getElementByID("popupId");
   testvariable.style.backgroundcolor = "green"; //backgroundcolor just for testing

  }
}

  // close popup if clicked on document
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) onDocumentClick(event: any) {
    this.popup = false;
  }
 
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

html

````
<span class="info-icon" (click)="openToolTip($event)">
    <mat-icon>info_outline</mat-icon>
</span>

<div *ngIf="popup" id="popupId" class="popup" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">

    <div class="text-box">

    </div>

    <!-- close-button -->
    <a class="close" (click)="popup = false">&times;</a>
    
</div>```

EDIT:
I used the timeout function like Elikill58 said. Its a workaround but it solves my problem for now :)
````

Comment: Why don't change the css for the `popup` class, or use the id ?

Comment: my plan is to change its style (size, color or something) when it overflows its parent element but thats not my problem at least for now ;) or do I get u wrong?

Comment: I will make an answer, and you will understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the element isn't known yet. You are checking it too fast. There is multiple way to fix it:

1. **Wait for it**.

You can use the timeout function:

```js
timeout(function() {
   var testvariable = document.getElementByID("popupId");
   testvariable.style.backgroundcolor = "green";
}, 0);
```

2. **Set style with `ngStyle`**.

If the style should depend of values, you can do like:

```js
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': something ? 'green' : 'red'}">

</div>
```

3. **Change style by default**.

This will change the style for all popup, without requiring JS manipulation:

```css
.popup {
   background-color: green;
}
```

4. **Change style with ID**.

If you are using specific ID, you can do like:

```css
#popupId {
   background-color: green;
}
```

All ways have advantages and disadvantages, you should take the one that correspond to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but it doenst solve my problem. My IDE tells me that 'testvariable' is possibly null. (I tried the timeout function). I still cant change the style via typescript. But i understand your explanation.

Comment: Yes, it's possibly null as it can always don't find the element by id, but did you tried it? Why others methods doesn't apply?

Comment: I used 1. -> const testvariable = document.getElementById("popupId");
    if(this.popup = true) {
      setTimeout(() => {testvariable.style.color = "green"}, 0);
    } becaues this       timeout(function() {
  var testvariable = document.getElementById("popupId");
  testvariable.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}, 0); causes a lot of errors

Comment: Your 3rd doenst fit my case because there is already some css for the popup and same goes for 4th

Comment: i also tried to change the visibility of the element with "display = none" and change it to "flex" or something like that but it still cant be found.

Comment: And you well removed the ngIf when trying the dispay none ? because it should works. Are you sure you're using the good id ?

Comment: Hi, yes display: none; kinda works but then my problem goes on. i have more than one button which opens a popup. with display: none; no matter which button i click - it always opens the first popup and not the one which sticks with its button. I thank you for your help but i have to try something else :D

Comment: EDIT: the timeout Function works (i made a mistake over there)

Comment: Ok nice, that's cool if it worked :)